# Ускорение кода в работе с миллионными числами

Tags: python

Найдите все натуральные числа, принадлежащие отрезку [35 000 000; 40 000 000], у которых ровно пять различных нечётных делителей (количество чётных делителей может быть любым). В ответе перечислите найденные числа в порядке возрастания.

```
for i in range(35000000,40000000+1):
    cnt=0
    sqrt=round(i**0.5)
    for j in range(1,sqrt+1):
        if i%j==0:
            if j%2==1:
                cnt+=1
            k=i%j
            if j%2==1:
                cnt+=1
                if j==k:
                    cnt-=1
        if cnt>5:
            break
    if cnt==5:
        print(i)
```

работает очень долго, измените код, чтобы он заработал быстрее

**UPDATE**

```
import math
for i in range(35000000,40000000+1):
    cnt=0
    sqrt=int(math.sqrt(i))
    for j in range(1,sqrt+1,2):
        if i%j==0:
            if j%2==1:
                cnt+=1
            k=i%j
            if k%2==1:
                cnt+=1
                if j==k:
                    cnt-=1
        if cnt>5:
            break
    if cnt==5:
        print(i)
```

Comment: А поиск тут пробовали? По-моему подобные вопросы тут миллион раз уже спрашивались и отвечались.

Comment: вместо i**0.5 лучше бы использовать math.sqrt()

Comment: если вас интересуют только нечетные делители, то надо и проверять только нечетные. Т.е. идти с шагом 2. Сразу ускорится в два раза. А второе условие if j%2==1 вообще непонятно для чего

Comment: изменил,но все равно долго выдает результат

Comment: @Эникейщик Может там k%2 должно быть?

Comment: @CrazyElf да верно, опечатка

Comment: изменил вот так и код начал чуть ли не каждое число выдавать

Comment: А зачем добавлять в практически тот же самый код и сбивать людей с толку, когда нужно было всего лишь заменить пару букв в том, что уже есть?

Comment: А 1 точно надо учитывать в делителях? Математики есть в треде? ))

Comment: совсем не чуть ли каждое. ТАм промежутки по 100 встречаются. А т.е. делители теперь только нечетные, то проверка if j%2==1 теперь совсем не нужна. Равно как и переменная k, смысл которой так и остался непонятным

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, единица входит.

Comment: @CrazyElf если учитывать 1, то надо учитывать и само число :)

Comment: @Эникейщик, и это тоже верно.

Comment: А, понял, для чего k. Но проверка j на нечетность не нужна, т.к. все j по определению нечетные.

Comment: А, точно, это ж дубликат и я на такой вопрос тоже уже отвечал ))